# Creating a custom OIDC claim/field on Google Identity

Tags: google-cloud-platform, openid-connect, google-workspace, google-identity

I am trying to create a custom claim in google identity for my application (xcreds) to pull from. Basically I'm trying to use xcreds mac password syncing tool and currently it works for users whos' usernames match their email format (jsmith) matches jsmith on the laptop local account. However, we have some users with local mac usernames named incorrectly (joesmith) that don't correctly match to the cloud record (jsmith)

I need to add a field to the OIDC record, say "LocalAccount" where I specify the local account name for the user account and then xcreds can pull from that name returned by Google.

The part im struggling with is how to add a custom OIDC claim to the google identity record. I understand this is possible with azure (doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-optional-claims) but I've not found a way to do this with Google Identity (google workspace, cloud, etc).

Is there a way to use one of the existing fields returned maybe?

https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration

```
"claims_supported": [
  "aud",
  "email",
  "email_verified",
  "exp",
  "family_name",
  "given_name",
  "iat",
  "iss",
  "locale",
  "name",
  "picture",
  "sub"
```

Maybe this just isn't possible, but wanted to ask the friendly hivemind :)

Documentation and research has not given me much to go on.

Comment: What are you using as the identity provider (Workspace or Identity Platform)? https://support.google.com/a/answer/6208725?hl=en&fl=1 and https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/admin/create-custom-tokens

Comment: We use workspace for user directory, and the consent screen is configured in Google cloud. I don't believe it's technically using Google identity. Forgive me, new at this.

Comment: Did the first link in my comment answer your questions?

Comment: So I guess at this point, the app can use the "sub" claim but now I can't figure out where in google workspace I can set this value on a user account. Any ideas?